# User activation code in android app

Tags: java, android, security, android-studio, activation

I need to add something that generate an activation code in my android app so the app features should work only if the app is activated. what is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, what you want to achieve is technically impossible.

Any functionality your app has is already there in the app, downloaded to the client. A user can use a debugger to disassemble the app file and change your source code to either not require an activation code or accept any code (whatever is easier, but both are possible). Anything you give to a client should be considered as being fully controlled by the client, any logic in there can be changed, secrets can be seen, etc.

This may not be straightforward, especially if you use some kind of an obfuscation, but it will always be possible. The question is only the effort needed.

And the effort is key here. In some scenarios, protecting low-value resources, it may be good enough to deter the lowest profile attackers. It's always about risk and the cost of protection. But you need to be aware of the above, that the logic in an app cannot be protected.

So if you want to protect your stuff, you have a few options for different scenarios:

- Have two separate apps, one free without paid functionality included and one paid. Users can use the free one and then buy the other if they want.
- Have paid functionality served by a server. If critical business logic is on the server side, you can really enforce access control rules and you can maintain control over who has access. This may have serious implications on your app architecture and functionality though.
- If the value you are trying to protect is low, you can go for obfuscation and access control logic in the app as mentioned above, but you need to be aware that this can be cracked relatively easily, especially on Android by changing the apk.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot do this with just your app, you definitely need the help of server which would generate an activation code for you and match it with the logged in user. Once the generated activation code is passed on to the user via email or any other means, then you can match the activation code given by the user and then match with the one in the server and if they match, let them use the features.

I hope this is what you want. But I might even be dumb enough to misunderstand you. Let me know if this is what you want.